# Spring Webflux Reactive Mongo vs Spring MVC Mongo performance difference

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-webflux

I have written two sample apps, one using Spring Webflux with Reactive Mongo driver and another using Spring MVC and the non-reactive Mongo driver. I have noticed huge performance differences between the two apps. The reactive one always has a response time more than 3 times higher compared to the MVC one.

Both apps connect to the exact same mongo instance ran via docker:

```
  mongo:
    image: mongo
    restart: always
    env_file:
      - ./env/mongo.env //just username and pass are set here, nothing else
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    volumes:
      - mongodb:/data/db
      - mongoconfigdb:/data/configdb
```

### Details about the implementations of the both apps below:

---

**application.yml** MVC and REACTIVE - These are identical in both apps

```
spring:
  data:
    mongodb:
      uri: mongodb://admin:nimda@localhost:27017
      database:
        data-name
      auto-index-creation: true
  application:
    name: data
```

**They both save the following model in mongo:**

```
@Document(collection = "data")
public class Data {

    @Id
    private String id;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

---

### MVC App code:

**Controller:** - basic rest controller

```
@RestController
public class BlockingController {

    private final BlockingMongoRepository blockingMongoRepository;

    public BlockingController(@Qualifier("blockingMongoRepository") BlockingMongoRepository blockingMongoRepository) {
        this.blockingMongoRepository = blockingMongoRepository;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/get", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public List<Data> getAllData() {
        return blockingMongoRepository.findAll();
    }
}
```

**Repository:** - basic mongo repo

```
@Repository(value = "blockingMongoRepository")
public interface BlockingMongoRepository extends MongoRepository<Data, String> {
}
```

Nothing fancy about the app, just retrieve all the data that is in the database.

**build.gradle:**

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
}
```

---

### Reactive App code

**Controller:** - just retrieves all the data in mongo

```
@RestController
public class ReactiveController {

    private final DataReactiveMongoRepository dataReactiveMongoRepository;

    public ReactiveController(@Qualifier("dataReactiveMongoRepository") DataReactiveMongoRepository dataReactiveMongoRepository) {
        this.dataReactiveMongoRepository = dataReactiveMongoRepository;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/get", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public Flux<Data> getAllData() {
        return dataReactiveMongoRepository.findAll();
    }
}
```

**Repository:**

```
@Repository(value = "dataReactiveMongoRepository")
public interface DataReactiveMongoRepository extends ReactiveMongoRepository<Data, String> {
}
```

**build.gradle:** - get reactive counterparts

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb-reactive'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux'
}
```

---

I have added 45000 data instances in mongo to test the difference between the implementations. On average, the mvc app returns them all in ~200-300ms while the reactive implementation returns them in ~2 seconds (2.1 seconds on average from my tests).

Regarding the **reactive controller**, I have also tried producing x-ndjson and application.json + collectList on the flux to return a list (same result, no performance improvement). When retrieving each item separately with x-ndjson the performance was much much worse.

The `@EnableReactiveMongoRepositories` is not needed since it's automatically added..i have also tried adding it manually but there is no difference.

From what I've been reading regarding Webflux + Mongo, i expected the performance to be somewhat similar ... maybe reactive should be a bit slower but the difference is huge and seems like something is misconfigured.

I have also played around and tried to publish/subscribe on the bounded elastic thread pool, but it does not seem to make any difference.

I have also ran a jMeter load test on both apps from another machine and the reactive implementation, in general, is ~3 times slower than the mvc one.

Whenever the data is kept in memory (in memory repo instead of mongo - nothing else changed) the reactive implementation performance is somewhat on par with the mvc one.
I have noticed the latency of the response is higher using reactive but the overall response time is around the same values.

---

**Reactive mongo client metadata:**

```
MongoClient with metadata {"driver": {"name": "mongo-java-driver|reactive-streams|spring-boot", "version": "4.6.1"}, "os": {"type": "Darwin", "name": "Mac OS X", "architecture": "x86_64", "version": "12.4"}, "platform": "Java/Eclipse Adoptium/17.0.4.1+1"} created with settings MongoClientSettings{readPreference=primary, writeConcern=WriteConcern{w=null, wTimeout=null ms, journal=null}, retryWrites=true, retryReads=true, readConcern=ReadConcern{level=null}, credential=null, streamFactoryFactory=NettyStreamFactoryFactory{eventLoopGroup=io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup@6cd64b3f, socketChannelClass=class io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel, allocator=PooledByteBufAllocator(directByDefault: true), sslContext=null}, commandListeners=[], codecRegistry=ProvidersCodecRegistry{codecProviders=[ValueCodecProvider{}, BsonValueCodecProvider{}, DBRefCodecProvider{}, DBObjectCodecProvider{}, DocumentCodecProvider{}, IterableCodecProvider{}, MapCodecProvider{}, GeoJsonCodecProvider{}, GridFSFileCodecProvider{}, Jsr310CodecProvider{}, JsonObjectCodecProvider{}, BsonCodecProvider{}, EnumCodecProvider{}, com.mongodb.Jep395RecordCodecProvider@51b01550]}, clusterSettings={hosts=[localhost:27017], srvServiceName=mongodb, mode=SINGLE, requiredClusterType=UNKNOWN, requiredReplicaSetName='null', serverSelector='null', clusterListeners='[]', serverSelectionTimeout='30000 ms', localThreshold='30000 ms'}, socketSettings=SocketSettings{connectTimeoutMS=10000, readTimeoutMS=0, receiveBufferSize=0, sendBufferSize=0}, heartbeatSocketSettings=SocketSettings{connectTimeoutMS=10000, readTimeoutMS=10000, receiveBufferSize=0, sendBufferSize=0}, connectionPoolSettings=ConnectionPoolSettings{maxSize=100, minSize=0, maxWaitTimeMS=120000, maxConnectionLifeTimeMS=0, maxConnectionIdleTimeMS=0, maintenanceInitialDelayMS=0, maintenanceFrequencyMS=60000, connectionPoolListeners=[], maxConnecting=2}, serverSettings=ServerSettings{heartbeatFrequencyMS=10000, minHeartbeatFrequencyMS=500, serverListeners='[]', serverMonitorListeners='[]'}, sslSettings=SslSettings{enabled=false, invalidHostNameAllowed=false, context=null}, applicationName='null', compressorList=[], uuidRepresentation=JAVA_LEGACY, serverApi=null, autoEncryptionSettings=null, contextProvider=null}
```

**Non-reactive mongo client metadata:**

```
MongoClient with metadata {"driver": {"name": "mongo-java-driver|sync|spring-boot", "version": "4.6.1"}, "os": {"type": "Darwin", "name": "Mac OS X", "architecture": "x86_64", "version": "12.4"}, "platform": "Java/Eclipse Adoptium/17.0.4.1+1"} created with settings MongoClientSettings{readPreference=primary, writeConcern=WriteConcern{w=null, wTimeout=null ms, journal=null}, retryWrites=true, retryReads=true, readConcern=ReadConcern{level=null}, credential=MongoCredential{mechanism=null, userName='admin', source='admin', password=<hidden>, mechanismProperties=<hidden>}, streamFactoryFactory=null, commandListeners=[], codecRegistry=ProvidersCodecRegistry{codecProviders=[ValueCodecProvider{}, BsonValueCodecProvider{}, DBRefCodecProvider{}, DBObjectCodecProvider{}, DocumentCodecProvider{}, IterableCodecProvider{}, MapCodecProvider{}, GeoJsonCodecProvider{}, GridFSFileCodecProvider{}, Jsr310CodecProvider{}, JsonObjectCodecProvider{}, BsonCodecProvider{}, EnumCodecProvider{}, com.mongodb.Jep395RecordCodecProvider@329548d0]}, clusterSettings={hosts=[localhost:27017], srvServiceName=mongodb, mode=SINGLE, requiredClusterType=UNKNOWN, requiredReplicaSetName='null', serverSelector='null', clusterListeners='[]', serverSelectionTimeout='30000 ms', localThreshold='30000 ms'}, socketSettings=SocketSettings{connectTimeoutMS=10000, readTimeoutMS=0, receiveBufferSize=0, sendBufferSize=0}, heartbeatSocketSettings=SocketSettings{connectTimeoutMS=10000, readTimeoutMS=10000, receiveBufferSize=0, sendBufferSize=0}, connectionPoolSettings=ConnectionPoolSettings{maxSize=100, minSize=0, maxWaitTimeMS=120000, maxConnectionLifeTimeMS=0, maxConnectionIdleTimeMS=0, maintenanceInitialDelayMS=0, maintenanceFrequencyMS=60000, connectionPoolListeners=[], maxConnecting=2}, serverSettings=ServerSettings{heartbeatFrequencyMS=10000, minHeartbeatFrequencyMS=500, serverListeners='[]', serverMonitorListeners='[]'}, sslSettings=SslSettings{enabled=false, invalidHostNameAllowed=false, context=null}, applicationName='null', compressorList=[], uuidRepresentation=JAVA_LEGACY, serverApi=null, autoEncryptionSettings=null, contextProvider=null}
```

---

```
OS: MacOS Monterey 12.6
Spring boot: 2.7.3
Java: Java/Eclipse Adoptium/17.0.4.1+1
```

Only one app was up during the tests..i have not ran a test on an app with the other one started.

Additionally i tried connecting to a mongo Atlas instance (Free) and I have noticed the same behaviour .. but this test is not really reliable.

My question is: why is this happening?
Are there some additional configs needed to leverage the power of webflux implementation?I could not find anything helpful in the docs.

Any info would be appreciated. Thank you!

**UPDATE**

I have noticed this behaviour only while using ReactiveMongoTemplate or ReactiveMongoRepository. If I use MongoClient (gradle dependency : 'org.mongodb:mongodb-driver-reactivestreams', which is also a dependency of spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb-reactive) the performance is much better than the mvc one, ~2.3 times the throughput for my tests.

Using ReactiveMongoTemplate or ReactiveMongoRepository blockhound instantly catches blocking calls, something which does not happen while using MongoClient. It seems the performance hit comes from blocking the event loop by spring mongo starter, though i would assume that would decrease throughput and not single request response time.